# jQuery - color tr by cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

Long story short - I'm displaying stock trades table *and* trying to set table row colors red or green meaning it's 'buy' or 'sell'.

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>board</th>
      <th>buysell</th>
      <th>openinterest</th>
      <th>price</th>
      <th>quantity</th>
      <th>seccode</th>
      <th>secid</th>
      <th>time</th>
      <th>tradeno</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>FUT</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>2912686</td>
      <td>67686</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>SiZ5</td>
      <td>3630</td>
      <td>23.09.2015 11:12:27</td>
      <td>1239572664</td>
    </tr>
```

`...etc`

using jQuery:

```
$("tr:contains('B')").addClass('greenBg');
$("tr:contains('S')").addClass('redBg');
```

but it actually colors row based on all content.

So, how should I address it to check only 'buysell' cell value ('B' to greenBg, 'S'  to redBg) and set color to the whole row, not only first cell?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```
var classes = {
  'B': 'greenBg',
  'S': 'redBg'
};

$('table.dataframe tbody tr').addClass(function() {
   return classes[this.cells[2].textContent];
});
```

If there is no corresponding key for the cell's `textContent` (`textContent` is not `B` or `S`), the function returns `undefined` and `addClass` doesn't add any class to that row.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('table.dataframe tr td').each(function(){
            if($(this).text() == 'B'){
              $(this).addClass('greenBg'); //colors the td
             //$(this).parent().addClass('greenBg'); //colors the entire row

           }
     else if($(this).text() == 'S'){
              $(this).addClass('redBg');
             //$(this).parent().addClass('redBg'); //colors the entire row

           }

   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you vey much! This helped a lot!

Comment: @pmus if this helped ..then you can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the `td` or the `tr` of the `nth-child`. So that it's only check for the table cell/row of the value you want.

I've done two examples one of colouring the whole row or just colouring the selected `td`'s

```
// Checks through the td elements which contain 'B' or 'S'
$("td:nth-child(3):contains('B')").addClass('greenBg');
$("td:nth-child(3):contains('S')").addClass('redBg');
```

[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE (Color to only the TD)](http://jsfiddle.net/1zLkt61k/2/)

```
// Checks through tr elements and find the td elements which contain 'B' or 'S'
$("tr:has(td:nth-child(3):contains('B'))").addClass('greenBg');
$("tr:has(td:nth-child(3):contains('S'))").addClass('redBg');
```

[JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE (Color to the whole row)](http://jsfiddle.net/m2smyLnf/2/)